# Error while compiling a .Rmd file to .pdf wit opencpu

Tags: r, opencpu

I have written a package in R, in that there is a function to compile .Rmd files to .pdf. The functionality enter code here of the function is as follows.

```
getPdf <- function(text){
  writeLines(text, con="input.Rmd");
  render("input.Rmd", bookdown::pdf_document2(toc = FALSE, fig_width=6,fig_height=4, fig_crop=FALSE, template="template01.tex", number_sections = FALSE))
}
```

This function works fine when I run locally.

I have installed this package into opencpu based docker image as I want to call this function through an API.

I have hosted opencpu instance in an EC2 and when I do the API call it gives me an error as follows.

> LaTeX failed to compile input.tex. See
>   https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See
>   input.log for more info.

When I log in to the docker image and if I run getPdf function directly through the console with the same input it works.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Does input.log have some relevant entries?

Comment: Could be a security permission error, see the sever manual and have a look at `/var/log.kern.log`.